# When searching for primes why is prime * prime > number a case to ignore?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms

That is to check to see if a number is a prime we check if it is divisible by previous primes.

However if the number we are checking is number, and prime * prime > number, where number is the number we are checking then...

we know all primes after this will not be a factor of number.

Why is this conceptually?

```
// simple code implementing this concept
function findPrimes(N) {
  const primes = [2];
  main: for (let i = 3; i <= N; i += 2) {
    for (let j = 1, prime; prime = primes[j++];) {
      if (prime * prime > i) break; // this line here
      if (i % prime === 0) continue main;
    }
    primes.push(i);
  }
  return primes;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you write “if the prime we are on is prime”?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note:  if $pq=n$ then $p\le\sqrt n$ or $q\le\sqrt n$

Comment: ? I don't understand that equation.  Is that from Calculus?

Comment: no it's from basic algebra of factorization.

Comment: @j.a.:  if $p\gt \sqrt n$ and $q\gt \sqrt n$ then $pq\gt\sqrt n\sqrt n=n$, so it can't be that $pq=n$

Comment: I see that it is Algebra and it makes sense that both can not be > square root of n.

Comment: I used to be good at math.  Time to go back to school :).

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to saying that you only need to check if a number $n$ is divisible by numbers between $1,2,\cdots,\sqrt{n}$. This is because if $d>\sqrt{n}$ and $d|n$, then $n/d<\sqrt{n}$, meaning that you would have already found another divisor, implying that checking above $\sqrt{n}$ is *redundant*.

Example: Take $n=34$. Then $\sqrt{n}=5.8\ldots$ . So if you want to check if $n$ is prime, you only need to check whether $2,3, 5$ divide $n$. Since $2$ divides 34, it's not prime. Notice that 34/2=17, and even though $17$ divides $34$, you've already accounted for it by checking $2$.

Comment: Conceptually ...? I have no idea what d|n means for starters.

Comment: $d|n$ means $d$ divides $n$; i.e., there's an integer $k$ such that $dk=n$

Comment: It may be better to take $n=34$ as an example, since $17$ is prime and $14$ is not

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Thank you, that is a better example!

Answer (score 1):

Let the prime be $p$

well $p$ divides $$p,2p,3p,4p,5p,6p,\ldots, (p+1)p,\ldots $$

That is, it divides every natural multiple of itself.

What we're looking for is the least prime factor of a number to eliminate it.

If we get to $p$ in our sieve, all numbers less than it have a smaller prime factor, so those multiples of $p$ would be eliminated by smaller primes. It follows that the square of $p$ is the lowest multiple of $p$ not knocked out.

If our number hasn't been knocked out by previous primes, it's least prime factor is at least $p$ . But that also implies( by above) it's greater than the square of $p$ .

In the case it's not, then we've got a contradiction to the implication, given. So it's least prime factor is itself.